# Blazor requesting a json file

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, blazor

I am trying to retrieve data from the server. But I can't get the json file from the server. I placed my json file in wwwroot/data/Users.json. This is my code. I receive this exception: Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find a part of the path "/data/Users.json".

```
@page "/"

@code{
    public class User
    {
        public string username;
        public string password;
    }
}
@{ 
    string json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("data/Users.json");
    User mahan = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);

<body>
    <h1>Usernsme: @mahan.username</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: above that line add line `System.IO.File.WriteAllText("data/UsersTest.json", "test")` and see where new file appears.

Comment: I did System.IO.File.WriteAllText("data/UsersTest.json", "test") but again it says the same error. I tried System.IO.File.WriteAllText("UsersTest.json", "test") and it worked but now the file isn't located in any directory of my project. I don't know where does it save the file but I guess that it saved it in iis worker process directory.

Comment: Blazor server or Blazor WebAssembly?

Comment: It's Blazor WebAssembly

Comment: Don't use NewtonSoft if you don't need it. Blazor is using System.Text.Json .

Comment: Is used this but the response is empty or null: User mahan = System.Text.Json.Serializer.Deserialize<User>(json);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Blazor Server you can use `File.ReadAllText("wwwroot/data/Users.json");`

In Blazor WebAssembly you don't provide the `wwwroot/` part but since File.ReadAllText() is not supported there it doesn't really matter.

Under WebAssembly you can `await Http.GetStringAsync("data/Users.json");`

Check FetchData.razor and weather.json for a full example.